# How to update data on Google App Engine NDB object so that it works fine for multiple write at the same time

Tags: database, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Here is the situation
I have a model like

```
class Content(ndb.Model):
    likeCount=ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)
    likeUser  = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User, repeated=True)
```

When a new content generate than a new "Content" object is generated like

```
content_obj_key = Content(parent=objContentData.key, #Where ContentData is     another ndb.Model subclass
                             likeUser=[],
                             likeCount=0
                           ).put()
```

And when any user like the same content than below function gets called

```
def modify_like(contentData_key, user_key):
    like_obj = Content.query(parent=contetData_key).get()
    if like_obj:
        like_obj.likeUser.append(user_key)
        like_obj.likeCount += 1
        like_obj.put()
```

**Problem:**
Now the problem is that when at the same time more than 4 user like the same content than this object write wrong data.
I mean lets say userA, userB, userC and userD like this data at the same time and currently only userE liked the same content.
So after all new four write the "likeCount" is not 5, always less than 5 and the "likeUser" list length is also less than 5.

So how can I solve this problem?
So that always data remains consistent.

Comment: If I remove the "parent" constraint that stated that "only 1 write/sec" than also same problem remains.

Comment: read about eventual consistency. there are many other s.o. questions and articles dealing with this.

Comment: Not only must eventual consistency be taken into account, but I also see no evidence of transactions being used, so overwriting results would be expected.  Queuing and batching updates could also be considered if you don't need realtime accuracy but do want accurate results.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that some of the updates are stepping on each other, since several users may be incrementing the same count value at the same time.

If userA and userB get the Content object at the same time - both having the same count value (likeCount=1).  Then both increment to value of 2 - when it should be total of 3.

One possible solution is to use sharding.  This is useful when entities in your application may have a lot of writes.  The count is the total of all shards for that entity.  Example code from the documentation:

```
NUM_SHARDS = 5

class SimpleCounterShard(ndb.Model):
    """Shards for the counter"""
    count = ndb.IntegerProperty(default=0)

def get_count():
    """Retrieve the value for a given sharded counter.

    Returns:
        Integer; the cumulative count of all sharded counters.
    """
    total = 0
    for counter in SimpleCounterShard.query():
        total += counter.count
    return total

@ndb.transactional
def increment():
    """Increment the value for a given sharded counter."""
    shard_string_index = str(random.randint(0, NUM_SHARDS - 1))
    counter = SimpleCounterShard.get_by_id(shard_string_index)
    if counter is None:
        counter = SimpleCounterShard(id=shard_string_index)
    counter.count += 1
    counter.put()
```

More info and examples on sharding counters can be found at:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

Comment: Thanks Jeff for your response. I'll try this and will let you know very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Use [transactions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions):

```
@ndb.transactional(retries=10)
def modify_like(contentData_key, user_key):
    ...
```

> A transaction is an operation or set of operations that are guaranteed
>   to be atomic, which means that transactions are never partially
>   applied. Either all of the operations in the transaction are applied,
>   or none of them are applied. Transactions have a maximum duration of
>   60 seconds with a 10 second idle expiration time after 30 seconds.

Comment: Brent the #transaction is guaranteed for atomic but what if both transaction reads the same value? In this case both will complete but the result will be wrong as Jeff and I illustrated by examples.

Comment: Because the set of operations in `modify_like()` is guarantee to be atomic, the later request will fail and have to retry.  It will then get the updated `like_obj` entity.